# Jump to a specific tab in WordPress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code which works on my localhost but does not work when I implement it on my live site, which is hosted on WordPress.

I have the below code on another page:

```
  <div class="smaller-col col-xs-6 col-md-3 product-thumb">
    <a href='<?php echo "/the-pods#{$product_id}"; ?>' target="_blank" class="thumbnail">
      <img class="img-responsive animated pulse eds-on-hover" src="<?php echo $product_image; ?>" width="120" height="120" alt="Hello Paisa">
    </a>
    <p><?php echo $product_tagline; ?></p>
  </div>
```

The above page links to the page with the code below:

```
<div id="exTab1" class="">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <?php
      $counter = 0; while($products->fetch()):
        $product_id = $products->field('product_id');
        $product_image = wp_get_attachment_url($products->get_field('product_logo.ID'));
    ?>
    <li class="<?php if($counter == 0){ echo 'active'; } ?>">
      <a href='<?php echo "#$product_id"; ?>' data-toggle="tab">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $product_image; ?>"/>
      </a>
    </li>
    <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
  <?php
    $counter_2 = 0; while($products_2->fetch()):
      $product_id_2 = $products_2->field('product_id');
      $product_image_2 = wp_get_attachment_url($products_2->get_field('product_logo.ID'));
      $product_desc_2 = $products_2->field('product_description');
      $product_website_2 = $products_2->field('product_website');
  ?>
    <div class="tab-pane <?php if($counter_2 == 0){ echo 'active'; } ?> fade in" id="<?php echo $product_id_2; ?>">
      <?php echo '#' . $product_image_2; ?>
      <?php echo "<p style='color:#777;'>" . $product_desc_2 . "</p>";?>
      <?php echo $product_website_2; ?>
    </div>
    <?php $counter_2++; endwhile; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var tabUrl = document.location.toString();
  if(tabUrl.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-pills a[href="#' + tabUrl.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
  }

  $('#nav-pills a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
  });
</script>
```

How do I implement the navigation part properly on Wordpress?

Comment: Have you checked your browser's console if there are some errors?

Comment: yes and i have no errors...